# Why did the openai's gym website close?

Tags: gym

Openai's gym website redirects to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/openai/gym).  Why did the openai's gym website close?

Comment: What was the answer you got on why it was shut down?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's shut down yet, for example, the environments are accessible here: https://gym.openai.com/envs/ Documentation and forum also work fine. But the main page gets redirected, as a result one can't sign in. It really seems like a deployment bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Open AI's Greg Brockman, the Gym website never had a big impact and so was never maintained. This is the reason he gives for shutting down the website.

A read only export of the site was archived at https://gym.openai.com/read-only.html and if you attempt to access the old website through the url https://gym.openai.com you will be redirected to the Open AI gym github repository.

For a while a static copy of the Open AI leader-board was maintained on the below url https://scoreboard-site-1764008611.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/ . However as of present the static site is also unreachable.

The Canadian AI startup montreal.ai had offered to maintain the gym website. However this offer was not taken up by open ai.

This issue was discussed in depth on the following threads

https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/6zvlm2/d_openai_closing_down_gym_toolkit_website/?st=jca6ia3n&sh=48a0d8f3

https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/718

Comment: The websites up